# How to make MouseWheel work on the scrollbar

Tags: c#, events, scrollbar, mousewheel

I am running an application in C# and I need to add Mouse Wheel functionality for a scroll bar.

I set `Focus()` on some controls from the window where I need that scroll. And still, it doesn't work. But if a minimize the application and maximize again and scroll without any other click it works.

If I click any other control, I cannot use the mouse wheel functionality on the scroll bar. Also, I put `Refresh()` on some controls.

What can be the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Can you specify: is this is WPF or WinForms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retarget the scroll wheel in VB.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559999/how-to-retarget-the-scroll-wheel-in-vb-net)

Comment: @Hans Passant I set Focus() on a control from the page but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It will create scrolling problems, It's not that the scroll position is being reset, but rather that the parent container is scrolling itself to the upper left corner of the user control.

To avoid this, you have to override the `ScrollToControl` method. Extend `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` and override the `ScrollToControl` method there.

Example code:

```
class CustomScrollBarPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
    {
        return this.AutoScrollPosition;
    }
}
```

Then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a MouseHover event handler and Focus() the scrollbar:

```
this.panel1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(panel1_MouseHover);

private void panel1_MouseHover (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.vScrollBar1.Focus();
}
```